# Jquery if Condition CSS

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I have This code:
The 'slideToggle' function it's working nice but the background color doesn't change.
Any tips? Thanks

jQuery:

```
$("#btnContactMob").on("click", function(){
  $("#contactMob").stop(true).slideToggle();
});

if (('#contactMob').is(':visible')) {
  $('#btnContactMob').css('background-color', '#FFF');
}
```

CSS:

```
#btnContactMob {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-top:1px solid #1a1a1a;
    font-family: Lato-Regular;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 26px;
}
    #contactMob {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Your `if` statement isn't inside your event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the condition check to the slideToggle callback

```
var $el = $('#contactMob');
var $btn = $("#btnContactMob").on("click", function () {
    $el.stop(true).slideToggle(function () {
        $btn.css('background-color', $el.is(':visible') ? '#FFF' : '');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/94ZEh/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed a $ in your if statement, try :

```
$("#btnContactMob").on("click", function(){
  $("#contactMob").stop(true).slideToggle();
});

if ($('#contactMob').is(':visible')) {
  $('#btnContactMob').css('background-color', '#FFF');
}
```

**Update**

Also agree with the above answer that you should do this check each time it is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for that, the problem persists thou

Comment: Have you tried the answer from Irvin Dominin aka Edward - this looks like it should solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a jquery `$` symbol:

```
if ($('#contactMob').is(':visible')) {
    $('#btnContactMob').css('background-color', '#FFF');
}
```

And the whole `if` needs moving inside the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Move you condition inside the `slideToggle` complete callback; you are missing a `$` in your condition.

Code:

```
$("#btnContactMob").on("click", function () {
    $("#contactMob").stop(true).slideToggle(function () {
        if ($('#contactMob').is(':visible')) {
            $('#btnContactMob').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        };
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/kLvnR/

Answer (score 0):

I assume this code is being executed at document ready? If so, the element #contactMob isn't visible at document ready, and that's it.

So you should run the "If visible" check, after you click the #btnContactMob so the check is being done after the click. Like so:

```
$("#btnContactMob").on("click", function(){
  $("#contactMob").stop(true).slideToggle();

  if ($('#contactMob').is(':visible')) {
    $('#btnContactMob').css('background-color', '#FFF');
  }
});
```

This way, when the #btnContactMob is clicked, the IF check is also executed again. A better way would be, to move the IF statement in the complete function of the "slideToggle". That way, the check is only executed after the "slideToggle" is done. So you are always sure it checks for visibility at the right moment. Like this:

```
$("#btnContactMob").on("click", function(){
  $("#contactMob").stop(true).slideToggle(function() { 
    if ($('#contactMob').is(':visible')) {
      $('#btnContactMob').css('background-color', '#FFF');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should reset the colour also once your element is hidden again :

```
$("#btnContactMob").on("click", function () {
    $("#contactMob").stop(true).slideToggle(function () {
        if ($('#contactMob').is(':visible')) {
            $('#btnContactMob').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        } else {
            $('#btnContactMob').css('background-color', '');
        }
    });
});
```